# how to Control Dynamic Input fields with react js usestate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have this JSON data to loop through the object and generate an input field based on the provide_no or provide_remark value as "Y".

I have successfully looped through the object and generated dynamic input fields.

**My main problem is I can't control the dynamic input field value.**

**JSON Data :**

```
const jsonData = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Item One",
    provide_no: "Y",
    provide_remark: "N",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Item One",
    provide_no: "Y",
    provide_remark: "Y",
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Item One",
    provide_no: "Y",
    provide_remark: "N",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "Item One",
    provide_no: "Y",
    provide_remark: "Y",
  },
];
```

**My Component :**

```
const Some = () => {
  const [init, setInit] = useState({
    id: 0,
    count: 0,
    count2: 0,
  });

  const handelChangeCount = (e) => {
    setInit({ ...init, id: e.target.id, count: e.target.value }); // this will change the all value of init state
  };
  const handelChangeCount2 = (e) => {
    setInit({ ...init, id: e.target.id, count2: e.target.value }); // this will change the all value of init state
  };

  return jsonData.map((d) => (
    <div key={d.id}>
      {d.provide_no === "Y" && (
        <input
          className="input w-auto"
          type="number"
          value={init.count}
          id={d.id}
          name="count"
          onChange={(event) => handelChangeCount(event)}
        />
      )}
      {d.provide_remark === "Y" && (
        <input
          className="input w-auto"
          type="number"
          value={init.count2}
          id={d.id}
          name="count2"
          onChange={(event) => handelChangeCount2(event)}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  ));
};
export default Some;
```

**I have tried to change the init state with handelChangeCount & handelChangeCount2 function**

```
  const handelChangeCount = (e) => {
    setInit({ ...init, id: e.target.id, count: e.target.value }); // this will change the all value of init state
  };
  const handelChangeCount2 = (e) => {
    setInit({ ...init, id: e.target.id, count2: e.target.value }); // this will change the all value of init state
  };
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what the problem is and what you are expecting. Can you please elaborate?